# Django ORM: Annotating a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

In order to simplify a very complicated query, I am trying to annotate a `User` to a `Submission` as if the user were a `ForeignKey` field.

Here is the (much simplified) core of my attempt so far:

```
import django.db.models as djdm
myfk = djdm.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=djdm.DO_NOTHING)
qs = Submission.objects.annotate(_user=
    djdm.Subquery(rcm.RQCuser.objects.values('pk')[:1],
                  output_field=myfk)
)
print(qs[0]._user.username)
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'username'

What do I need to do to convince Django that `_user` should end up as a relation to a `User` model instance?

Furthermore, my actual complex query shows a different symptom (at what I had hoped would be the equivalent spot):

> AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'model'

Can anybody contribute a guess what the origin of this may be?

Comment: it looks like you're setting the `_user` attribute as a pk (int). It's been awhile since I've used Django tbh but you could try something like: `_user=rcm.RQCuser.objects.all().first()` instead

Comment: @nihilok Thanks. No, Django accepts only a single column for `annotate()`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Subqueries can only return a single column of user, and not the whole user instance. Is getting the exact field you need from user not enough?

Comment: @bdbd I need a bunch of fields from user, but yes, I may have to fall back to that. But just like a normal model stores just a `ForeignKey` to provide access to a whole model instance, an annotation should be able to do this, too. Not?